# Does A bit + adj sound right?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I think this isn't grammatically correct but rather a thing used in a daily language.
Can

> For a bit less work, we skipped that part...

be the same as

> We skipped that part to not do a very small job/work/task.

My most concern comes from the 'a bit less' part as it doesn't seem so right to me. Is it okay to say something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ***a bit*** is simply a synonym of "slightly, a little":

> We use *a bit* ***to modify adjectives***, *or as an adverb*. ***It is more informal*** than *a little*:
>
> - They had got ***a bit** tired* working in the garden.
>
> ***A bit*** is also used ***to modify comparative adjectives and comparative determiners***:
>
> - The climate in New Zealand was ***a bit nicer*** than we had expected. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/a-bit))

In your sentence, ***a bit*** is used exactly in the same way: it modifies the comparative adjective ***less***:

> For ***a bit** less* work, we skipped that part...

means that we skipped a part *for a little less work* (in order to work less).

Answer (score 1):

It’s clear what you mean though it sounds a bit clumsy. You wouldn’t really use ‘for a bit’ in that context.

You need a verb in sentence one i.e. ‘In order to do a bit less work we skipped that part’ or ‘So that we could do a bit less work we skipped that part’

Those are how most English people would phrase what you mean.

Comment: In writing you may be right. But in spoken language and internet culture, the use of the  ellyptic "for a bit less work(/or something else)" has been increasing, though I cannot prove it :)